# jQuery selector and cloning in a smart fashion

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble finding the way to solve this issue. I have this ul-menu output by Wordpress:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I want the end result to be like this - cloning and appending the anchor and put a clone below:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have used jQuery - but I am not having any luck at all for 2 hours of trial and error. This is as close as I can get. But it is wrong.

```
/*jQuery*/
$('.menu li a:first-child').eq(0).clone().insertAfter('.menu li a:first-child');
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/67jXz/1/

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to `.eq(0)`; that will limit it to the first `a` element that's matched, so that will be cloned and inserted after every subsequent `a`, resulting in copies of "Page 1".

Instead, you need to perform the cloning and inserting for *each individual element* by iterating with `.each()`, like so:

```
$('.menu li a:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);
});
```

Note that the `.insertAfter(this)` part refers to inserting the cloned element *after the original element* that was matched by the `.menu li a:first-child` selector; the same `this` in `$(this)` that references the matched element.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/67jXz/2)

Comment: That works! I was trying with a .each, but would never gotten it just as sweet as your lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.menu li a:first-child').each(function(k,v){
    $(v).clone().insertAfter(v);
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoku2010/VbWXj/)